# How to get google tag manger variable value in custom HTML

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I have dynamic values in my Datalayer which I want to access from my custom HTML in Google Tag Manager

Custom HTML in tag : {A pixel image for tracking orders}

```
<img src="https://httpool-secure.net/p.ashx?o=59&e=51&f=img&t={{transactionId}}&etc={{transactionTotal}}" width="1" height="1" border="0"
```

My DataLayer Object :

```
[{
    "event": "ordersuccess",
    "transactionId": 86886,
    "transactionAffiliation": "Powai",
    "transactionTotal": 158,
    "transactionTax": 17.5,
    "transactionProducts": [{
        "sku": "2395",
        "name": "Masala Calzone ",
        "category": "OTHERS",
        "price": "70",
        "quantity": "2"
    }]
}, {
    "gtm.start": 1454584525056,
    "event": "gtm.js"
}, {
    "event": "gtm.dom"
}, {
    "event": "gtm.load"
}]
```

[Data Layer Variable transactionId](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dPw6O.png)

[Data Layer Variable transactionTotal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kVHwi.png)

Now when I publish my tag I get errors :

> Unknown variable 'transactionTotal' found in a tag. Edit the tag and
>   remove the reference to the unknown variable.
>
> Unknown variable 'transactionId' found in a tag. Edit the tag and
>   remove the reference to the unknown variable.

How to associate the variables to my tag ???

Comment: Use the name you gave to your variables in GTM ("transaction_id" and "total transaction"), not the name of the Javascript variables.

Comment: @EikePierstorff is most likely correct (but why isn't he posting this as a solution?) :-)

Comment: "He" thinks this is a trivial oversight on the part of the OP that does not necessitate a full-blown answer :-)

Comment: Trivial or not, it is (I believe) the solution. "He" is too humble.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The top field sets the variable name in GTM Panel. 
Please use that name as the variable name . 
You should be using the name of the DataLayer Variables that you've named in this input box, and not the name of the dataLayer parameters themselves

Answer (score 3):

I take no credit for this possible answer as it was already mentioned in comments (props to @EikePierstorff), but as a formality, here it is:

You should use the name of the DataLayer Variables that you've defined, and not the name of the dataLayer parameters themselves:

```
<img src="https://httpool-secure.net/p.ashx?o=59&e=51&f=img&t={{transaction_id}}&etc={{total transaction}}" ...
```

Answer (score 2):

Even though the correct answer is already given, I really understood it until I saw the documentation in this repository:
https://github.com/BKWLD/data-layer-events

The key is part of the `README.md` file in the `Setup` section.

Basically you need to setup variables of type `Data Layer Variable` with the parameter name you're giving, in your case that would be `transactionId`, then the variable becomes available on the tags and it will match the JS parameters you are providing.

Answer (score 1):

As some have mentioned, you need to use the variable's name when referencing it in HTML. For example: If I setup a variable named 'Order Total' but the Data Layer Variable Name is orderTotal you'll want to use 'Order Total' in your HTML as displayed below.

alert({{Order Total}});